# How to make glob.glob() depth-first?

Tags: python

I've noticed `glob.glob('**/*', recursive=True)` walks the directory in a breath-first search fashion. Is there a way to make it depth-first?

Comment: No, but maybe you'd like to peruse the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/glob.py#L23) and implement a DFS version yourself?

Comment: How about using `os.walk()` to do the DFS, then `glob.glob()` (non-recursive) in the directories it returns.

Comment: In this case there is no need to `glob` anything at all; `os.walk` can do the entire job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To walk a directory tree, switch to [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) which lets you control this (viz. via its `topdown` keyword argument).

The purpose of `glob` is to parse wildcard patterns, but you don't seem to have any specific wildcard pattern. If you want to apply a pattern to the file and directory names, do that inside an `os.walk()`.

Comment: Well done - your answer includes *exactly* the right amount of code to match the question! Upvote.